# strict henselian and excellent henselian

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello, everyone. I want to ask a problem about strict henselian ring.

Let $A$ be a strict henselian DVR.

Dose there exist subrings $A_{i}$ of $A$, such that $A=lim_{i} A_{i}$ and where $A_{i}$ are excellent strict henselian DVR.

Comment: Please can you clarify your question? The rings $A_i$ cannot be both strictly henselian and finitely generated over [an] integral number ring; for example, a strictly henselian ring has a separably closed, so infinite, residue field, and the other class have finite residue fields.

Comment: sorry, I modified the problem.